# Can I use Java NIO2?

Tags: nio, java

I am working on a project where I've to implement Distributed File System, so for I/O operations, I was thinking of using [NIO2 (JDK7)](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/)

JDK7 will be [released in August](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/) next year.

My questions are:

1. Would it be good idea to use NIO2 from snapshot of JDK7 ? What problems can I face?
2. If I compile my code which uses both JDK6 and JDK7 classes is it possible to compile using JDK7 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1 - Would it be good idea to use NIO2 from snapshot of JDK7 ? What problems can I face?

For a student / research project I see no major issues, apart from the general ones like:

- new APIs *may* still be in a state of flux, and *may* change without notice,
- you are more likely to encounter JDK/JRE/JVM bugs, and
- people who want to try out your project have to use JDK 7.

For a project that needs to go into production before the *actual* release of JDK 7, you probably should be more cautious.

> 2 - If I compile my code which uses both JDK6 and JDK7 classes is it possible to compile using JDK7?

You cannot be certain until you actually try it, but I'd be very surprised if the answer is anything other than "yes".  The Java team are very aware of the need to maintain backwards compatibility.

(However, it is unlikely that you'll be able to compile using JDK 6 ... unless they decide that it is technically feasible and worthwhile to provide a backport of the feature for JDK 6.  For something like NIO2, it could be "no" on both counts.)